# Trying to setup a specific network config using 2 routers

Tags: networking, windows-10

Just want to know if this is possible at all, by messing with routing rules, making a network bridge etc.

I want to share the internet connection over my ethernet port, yet still have it access devices over said ethernet port, like it were just connected to a LAN.

[image: Annotation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a FAQ (or a variation of one).

Your PC needs to do network address translation (NAT) between the LAN and WLAN. Under Windows 10, that's a "share your internet" variant (but in the other direction than normally used, you don't need a WLAN AP to share the LAN connection, but the other way round).

For the router, use it as a simple switch. Most home routers (you didn't give any information about your router) that works if you just use the three of the four LAN ports.

You can either leave DHCP on the router on, or disable DHCP on the router, and let Windows 10 do the DHCP.

Pick a network prefix that's different from your WLAN prefix (i.e., if you use `192.168.1.*/24` for WLAN, use `192.168.2.*/24` for the LAN).